# Custom Raised Button action not navigates to Tabbarİtem

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

İ  have created a custom raised button in `tabbarviewcontroller`. Already added a custom action on button for selectedindex = 2. 
Problem I am facing first time button clicked is working fine shows second tabbar item and perform action but if I re-clicked button again it won’t show tabbar item view. To check button status I use print command and its printing that button clicked.

> Tabbarviewcontroller —> tabbarİtem 2 —> webview

As it stays on webview controller but On re-click of button İ need it come backs(navigates) to tabbarİtem 2.(refresh view as navigatecontroller performs back button). Behind the custom button - tabbarbar item for item2 (link able) is working but not on button.

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

    print("clicked button")
    selectedIndex = 2   //// button click to open tabbar item 2

}
```